# Building an NSPredicate from objects in an array throws "Unable to parse the format string" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` of strings that need to be used to construct an `NSPredicate` format. This predicate is then used for a core data fetch request.

For some reason the following produces a "Unable to parse the format string" error.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

```
NSArray *multipleStrings = [multipleText componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableString *predicateString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSString *sizeString in multipleStrings) {
    [predicateString appendFormat:@"AND ANY containerType.typeID.intValue == %i ", sizeString.intValue];
}

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@ %@", self.group.people, predicateString];
```

I would have hoped it would have created a dynamic predicate format like the following:

```
@"SELF IN %@ AND ANY containerType.typeID.intValue == 2 AND ANY containerType.typeID.intValue == 4 AND ANY containerType.typeID.intValue == 10"
```

Comment: What happens if you try `SELF IN %@ AND %@`?

Comment: That gives me `Unable to parse the format string "SELF IN %@ AND %@`.

Comment: I think `predicateWithFormat` might only be expecting a single "$@", so maybe try removing the second one and see if there's still an error; otherwise you might need to use a compound predicate, or something of the like...

Comment: Yeah I might just go with compound predicate.

Comment: NSPredicate format works bit differently than you are doing here. It expects that the format is pure equation to filter the sequence and the argument given to it are either value or label if used with %K, you cannot concatenate string in NSPredicate format. Concatenate it outside and use that insde the format string.

Comment: @Sandeep I have tested it with `NSCompoundPredicate` and I can achieve the result I wanted. I was just worried that using `SELF IN` multiple times in the compound would slow things down. But likely Apple has optimized that internally.